# Optimizing count of mongodb with spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to get total number of records resulted by a particular mongo query. The total records are about 90k. I am using spring data mongo to achieve this.

My code looks like below -

```
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate();
int count = (int) mongoTemplate.count(query, collectionName);
```

Here query is constructed based on user request, so it's not known beforehand. This is giving result in about 6 secs, which is too much for our application, and thus the request just times out.

I tried indexing one field that was being used in the query, like below -

```
int count = (int) mongoTemplate.count(query.withHint("fieldName"), collectionName);
```

Performance improved a little, but still many times it went upto 6 secs.

I then tried to make multiple calls to mongo, by using skip/limit in CountOptions, like below -

```
int limit = 1000;
    int offset = 0;
    int total = 0;
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");
    query.fields().include("_id");

    while (total == offset) {

        CountOptions countOptions = new CountOptions().hintString("fieldName").limit(limit).skip(offset);

        total += (int) collection.count(query.getQueryObject(), countOptions);
        offset += limit;
    }
```

I don't know what goes on behind the scenes in this logic, but the time actually got increased to about 20 secs. with this. I don't know what I maybe doing wrong here.

Is there any other way I can get the count of the records returned by a query, in an optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

To return how many documents match a query, all of the documents need to be identified by the server. This basically means a count is equivalent to performing the find with all of the conditions and going through all of the results in the server (the results aren't put on the wire to be returned to the client but everything else happens).

This means:

1. Count operations in general take as long as the finds do, and sometimes significantly longer if finds are limited (since it does not make sense to limit a count).
2. All indexing considerations that apply to finds also apply to counts.

So, you need to look at your conditions and indexes and ensure that your indexes can be used by your query.